How Do Time Driven Triggers Run In add-on standalone scripts
Maybe this question is basic, but I'm trying to understand the nature of time-driven triggers in standalone scripts used for add-ons.
I understand that in bound scripts, the time-driven triggers run in the context of the bound the document/sheet, and because of that, the trigger can access the document/sheet instance.
But what happens when you have a time-driven trigger installed in, for example, a public add-on? Does it run once-every-X-time, or does it run every-X-time for each document in which it has been installed on?
i.e. 10 users install my add-on, does the time-driven trigger execute 10 times? Or does it run only one fixed time? And if it runs only one time, does that mean that i must make all the changes necessary for all my users in only a single function execution?

The triggers actually belong to the project and both standalonne and bound scripts have projects.

Time-driven triggers are installable triggers associated with a project and the user who created the trigger.
The executions will depend on the number of triggers created, not the number of users who installed your add-on.
Begin by clearly defining the process of creating a trigger and identifying the user who will create it. It's not essential to use a bound or a stand-alone project for publishing an Editor add-on for Google Sheets; in both cases, the Editor add-on for Google sheets will work as a script bound to the spreadsheet on which the add-on is activated.
Related

Is it possible to create time driven triggers in Google Sheet Add On?
Time-driven triggers scope in Google Script
How many time based trigger can your add-on run on a document / user?


As mentioned in the previous answer, I can add a few more information about the Time-driven triggers and regarding your concern about the executions of the trigger.
Apps Script triggers cause a specified script function (the trigger function) to execute whenever a specified event occurs. Only certain events can cause triggers to fire, and each Google Workspace application supports a different set of events.
I assume that you are using the triggers for the Add-ons that are mentioned here https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers
Each add-on can only have one trigger of each type, per user, per document and with that said yes you will only make all the changes necessary for all your users only in a single function.
Answring to your question the triggers that is time drive will run once-every-X-time no matter how many people have installed the add-on that you created.
You can check and see more information about the triggers for add-ons here:https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your assumption is wrong (time-driven triggers are not listed on the referred page; that page is about Workspace add-ons, but this question is about a different type of add-on).

I was not talking about time-driven triggers because they mentioned this type of trigger as an example, the page I mentioned is about triggers for add-ons which explains how the triggers work in a created add-on. From this documentation you can go and find the time-driven trigger, but it was just an example, not the fact of the question. Question owner was talking about execution for the triggers which is what I explained.
